# Contact us via dpo@company.com vs. Contact us at dpo@company.com

Tags: prepositions

I'm proofreading a text and have come across this sentence:

> You can contact the personal data protection officer of the Sponsor at: dpo@company.com

I think it should be **via** instead of **at** because **at** usually implies some "more constant" location like a website. Am I right, or maybe **at** could be used here?

Comment: The only thing wrong with the sentence is the use of the colon with only a single list item. The preposition itself is fine, and probably the most common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Via" means "by way of", or "through". For example, if I was travelling from place [A] to place [C], I might go *via* place [B]. That means that place [B] was never my destination, it was just somewhere I went through to get where I wanted to go.

In the context of your example, we do say "via email" or "via telephone" when talking about contact methods - that is because the contact method is something that sits in-between the two parties. For example, "you can contact me via email".

However, it doesn't seem right to use this with a specific email address, even though you could probably find loads of examples where English speakers do. Think about my example of travel - you would say you went via a place you travelled through, but an address would be your final destination.

Really, you should use "via" or "by" when broadly referring to the means of contact (phone, email etc), but use "on" or "at" when referring to a specific address or phone number. People tend to say "on" with a phone number, and "at" for an email address, for example:

> - You can contact me *via* email *at* example@example.com.
> - You can contact me *by* telephone *on* 0555 123456.

Speaking as a former IT specialist, I personally don't like saying "at" when it comes to citing email addresses, because the @ symbol in an email address is also "at", and it just sounds odd to me to repeat that word. However, others argue that "at" follows the convention of email addresses, and so should be used. This seems to be more of an IT jargon issue than an English language issue.